# Tradingview (Pine Script) Array is to long

Tags: pine-script

I have a script where i want to load a bunch of data points inside an Array, except when loading about 20 items it already errors out on this error:

Study Error
Array is to large, Maximum size is 1000000

Any thoughts how to circumvent this?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are probably misusing a function.

Comment: Maybe you're using a `var` array. Again, cannot guess without a code.

Comment: Thanks for these answers, srry for my late response, i was away for a while. I will post a minimal reproducible example, thanks for reminding me @vitruvius